# .then() not executing the interior function multiple times during a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, promise

I'm working on a piece of code that's implementing promises. It's inside a loop and iterates over the number of images input into the page. First it should update the canvas with a new image and then it should run some code to get info from the canvas image. Here are my current functions.

Here is what changes the image to the next one in the input.

```
function readNextImage(i) {
  d = new $.Deferred();
  if (fileUpload.files && fileUpload.files[i]) {
    var FR = new FileReader();
    FR.onload = function(e) {
      fabric.Image.fromURL(e.target.result, function(img) {
        img.set({
          left: 0,
          top: 0,
          evented: false
        });
        img.scaleToWidth(canvas.width);
        img.setCoords();
        canvas.add(img);
      })
      var imgData = context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
      d.resolve(imgData);
    };
    FR.readAsDataURL(fileUpload.files[i]);
  }
  return d.promise();
}
```

And here is a snippet of the other function that is called in the .then() command.

```
function read_image (imgData) {
    console.log("in read_image");
    data = imgData.data;
    /*doing some stuff to the data object*/ 
    console.log("here is some data output");
}
```

And finally here is what calls both of the functions

```
for (var image_num=0; image_num<fileUpload.files.length; image_num+=1){
    console.log("loop:"+image_num);
    promise = readNextImage(image_num).then(read_image);    
}
```

So what is happening is that the canvas is being updated with the new images but only once the final image is updated to the canvas is when I see any console.logs from the `read_image()` function, and I only see a single output. Here's a sample of the console output.

```
loop:0
loop:1
loop:2
loop:3
loop:4
loop:5
loop:6
loop:8
in read_image
here is some data output
```

Any insight as to why the function inside of then() is only being called one time would be most appreciated.

Comment: one possible issue is that you only resolve the deferred `if (fileUpload.files && fileUpload.files[i]) {` - otherwise you leave it hanging

Comment: There's also no error handling on the `FileReader()` operations and thus the promise gets hung up forever if there's an error.

Comment: You also don't wait for `fabric.Image.fromURL()` (which is presumably asynchronous) to complete before resolving your promise.

Comment: what you want to add also is some console.log's in `readNextImage` to see which part of that code is actually being executed

Comment: You also need to declare `d` as local to the function with `let`, `const` or `var`.  You may be overwriting a higher scoped `d` and then resolving the wrong one.

Comment: @jfriend, that's actually the cause of the issue described!

Comment: @AussieJoe - Because the code does not work properly.  Codereview is only for working code that someone wants to improve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare `d` as local to the function with `let`, `const` or `var`. You are likely overwriting a higher scoped `d` and then resolving the wrong one.

```
function readNextImage(i) {
  var d = new $.Deferred();
//^^^
```

Other issues:

1. There's no error handling on the FileReader object so any error will cause your promise never to resolve or reject.
2. You don't wait for `fabric.Image.fromURL()` (which is presumably asynchronous) to complete before resolving your promise.
3. If your `if` statement here is not satisfied `if (fileUpload.files && fileUpload.files[i])`, then you will never resolve or reject the promise.

Here's an attempt at cleaning up those four issues (with no ability to test the code to make sure it's completely right):

```
function readNextImage(i) {
    var d = new $.Deferred();
    if (fileUpload.files && fileUpload.files[i]) {
        var FR = new FileReader();
        FR.onload = function(e) {
            fabric.Image.fromURL(e.target.result, function(img) {
                img.set({
                    left: 0,
                    top: 0,
                    evented: false
                });
                img.scaleToWidth(canvas.width);
                img.setCoords();
                canvas.add(img);
                var imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                d.resolve(imgData);
            });
        };
        FR.onerror = function(e) {
            d.reject(e);
        }
        // start the file reader
        FR.readAsDataURL(fileUpload.files[i]);
    } else {
        // not sure what you want to do here, but you need to resolve or reject the promise
        d.resolve()
    }
    return d.promise();
}
```

---

When writing code with multiple async operations that don't already deal in promises, it is generally better to "promisify" each asynchronous operation at the lowest level.  This, then lets you consistent write all your program logic using the sequencing and flow control and error handling of promises (which is a big advantage).  You could do that in this case like this:

```
function readFileDataURL(f) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = resolve;
        fr.onerror = reject;
        fr.readAsDataURL(f);
    });
}

function imageFromURL(data) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fabric.Image.fromURL(data, resolve)
    });
}

function readNextImage(i) {
    if (fileUpload.files && fileUpload.files[i]) {
        return readFileDataURL(fileUpload.files[i]).then(function(e) {
            return imageFromURL(e.target.result);
        }).then(function(img) {
            img.set({
                left: 0,
                top: 0,
                evented: false
            });
            img.scaleToWidth(canvas.width);
            img.setCoords();
            canvas.add(img);
            var imgData = context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
            return imgData;
        });
    } else {
        // nothing to do here
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
}
```

Notice, you also get two utility functions that work in promises that you could perhaps reuse elsewhere.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much, really appreciate the help and advice! I'm still pretty novice to javascript/html so any pointers are always appreciated.

Comment: @JakeMcClenny - I added another version of the code to show a different way of writing it.

Comment: That is very useful information. I greatly appreciate you taking your time to educate me!